# NE555 delay before turn-on

Tags: 555

To implement a delay before turn-on I implemted this circuit and it works as expected.

When I switch on, the led is on after few second as expected. fine. When I switch off, the LED still light few second, time to capacitor to discharge...

How is it possible to quickly discharge the capacitor?

[image]

inspired from

[image]

Comment: Do you have a source for that yellow image?  Where did you get it from?

Comment: If you eliminate everything else, a simple R-C circuit of 10 uF and 220 ohms has a time constant of 2.2 ms. Discharged down to 1%, that's 5 time constants or 11 ms. Throw in the LED Vf needed for operation and that gets even shorter.  If the LED is staying on for "a few seconds", there is some other energy source.

Comment: Source : https://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/50%20-%20555%20Circuits/50-555Circuits.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a lower capacitance while increasing the resistance to keep the timing the same, for example 0.1uF and 100k. If the capacitor is holding enough charge to power the circuit by itself, a smaller cap won't hold as much energy, and I believe the current path when powered off is through the resistor, so a high value won't allow enough current for the LED to light.

Even a 10 uF capacitor charged to 9 V shouldn't light an LED for more than a second or two, if it's more than that there must be some other power source, make sure the supply voltage is being fully switched off.

Comment: yeah ! nice idea :-)

Comment: hum, it's not relevant as expected :-( The LED stays ON for a long time, as pin 3 will not go low.... strange. This is another problem. I will diagnose deeper my circuit

Comment: @hervema Are you disconnecting all voltage source with a switch as shown? Even a 10uF cap shouldn't be able light an LED for very long, there must be current coming from somewhere else.

Comment: In the real circuit on my breadboard, all the power sources (+) were not disconnected with my switch, causing erratic operation. In front of my eyes, and I couldn't see! :-( Thanks (all) !